# Why I got Illegal arguments error with simple hash function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(11);

const user = {
    first: "Donald",
    last: "Trump",
    password : bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt),
    greetUser(password) {
      console.log(`Hi, ${this.first} ${this.last} ${this.password}`);
    },
  };
  
  let password = 'secondhand01';
  user.greetUser(password);
```

I run

```
node --trace-warnings index.js

Hi, Donald Trump [object Promise]
(node:15222) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, object
```

I expected hashed password. Why does terminal point to illegal arguments?

Comment: You get the error because `this.password` is not set when the `bcrypt.hash` function is run. It returns a promise causing the `[object Promise]` in the console.log. `bcrypt.hash` will then get chance to run and throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an object literal, `password : bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)` **calls** `bcrypt.hash` and assigns its return value to the `password` property. In the code you've shown, `this` *doesn't* refer to the object being created, it refers to the same thing `this` refers to where the object literal is being created (the top level of the module). Since that doesn't have a `password` property, you're passing `undefined` to the function.

`bcrypt.hash` also returns a promise, as you can see from the output you get before the unhandled promise rejection.

Your `user` object is being populated with hardcoded values, so you may have meant to do something like this:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(11);

bcrypt.hash("secondhand01", salt) // <=== Encrypt the password
.then(hashedPassword => {
    // You have it now, you can build and use the object
    const user = {
        first: "Donald",
        last: "Trump",
        password : hashedPassword,
        greetUser() { // Note I removed the parameter you weren't using here
          console.log(`Hi, ${this.first} ${this.last} ${this.password}`);
        },
    };
      
    user.greetUser(); // Note I removed the unused argument here
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report the error...
});
```